# How can i fix error getline and ostringstreaming C++?

Tags: c++, command-line

Hello i make the program for whitelist firewall but i can't fix error,the message like this

> One or more of the specified profiles is  not valid. 'Any' cannot be specified if other profiles are specified.

my program like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    start:
    system("title WHITELIST FIREWALL");
    FILE* codefile;
    if (codefile = fopen("C:\\Windows\\disable.dl", "r")) {
        fclose(codefile);
        goto no;
    }
    else {
        goto firewall;
    }
no:
    system("cls");
    system("echo Please Turn On Firewall Filter First");
    system("pause");
    goto start;

firewall:
    std::string Name;
    std::string Directory;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Name: ";
    getline(cin, Name);
    cout << "Directory Application: ";
    getline(cin, Directory);
    std::ostringstream oss(Name);
    std::ostringstream osss(Directory);
    oss << "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=" << Name << " dir=in action=allow program=" << Directory << " enable=yes";
    system(oss.str().c_str());
    osss << "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=" << Name << " dir=out action=allow program=" << Directory << " enable=yes";
    system(osss.str().c_str());
    system("del C:\\Windows\\rules.wfw");
    system("netsh advfirewall export C:\\Windows\\rules.wfw");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me fix the error ?

I want to make whitelist firewall

Comment: If you execute the commands you're putting together on the command line do they work? If not, then executing them with system isn't going to work either. Print out what you're passing to system to see if it makes sense.

Comment: @Retired Ninja yes it works if i use system but fails when i use ostringstreaming together with system string and getline

Comment: What is the input you're providing?

Comment: @Retired Ninja like this and error https://ibb.co/yssT65H before this i use std::cin but thats not work if use space

Comment: Text please. Add it to your question.

Comment: @Retired Ninja i use std::cin before and thats not work with space after that i use getline but its not work on netsh advfirewall so the input can't show in system netsh advfirewall